# Is there a way to work with Microsoft OneDrive files in another office suite such as LibreOffice?

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive, libreoffice

At work, we work with MS Office and online files hosted in OneDrive. This permits the people edit the same document at the same time.

That works there, but at home no. Because no everybody has the MS Office at home. Someone uses Linux, so they use MS Word Online but this option isn’t very good. Because the MS Office Online doesn’t have all the tools that the MS Office desktop version have.

Is there a way to conect to the domain [d.docs.live.net](http://d.docs.live.net) using another program, like WPS Writer or LibreOffice to the OneDrive for work online.

Comment: Just open and saved the document within the OneDrive folder on the machine in question.  Mutliple people being able to edit a single document is a feature of the word processor but more importantly Office 365.  OneDrive is just where the document is being stored, it could be in any location, multiple devices could see.  The only change to the desktop retail version of Office that was made, is its aware of the OneDrive folder, but the folder is a physical location on the device so that isn't anything special really.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You said: _Mutliple people being able to edit a single document is a feature of the word processor but more importantly Office 365_. But we tried to use Ms Word with dropbox and we couldn't edit the same document at the same time. For this, I think maybe It's a feature of Office 365 but that it works only with the OneDrive. But I don't know it.

Comment: Office 365 is a single term that describes two seperate things.  The first thing, is the word processor installed on the client, the second is the online service.  If the feature your asking about is a feature of the online service, then a word processor would have to integrate with the service, which is unlikely going to happen with WPS Writer or LibreOffice.

Comment: I understood. So there isn't a way to work simultaneously with another word processor

Comment: Google Documents allows you to do that.